# Attending training school while looking for a job

Tags: resume

I have a gap in my resume not working in period of one year and half, but during that period I was attending in professional training school for 8 months and the rest was study for exam and got couple certifcations related my profession.  Should i include in my resume to fill the gap . Please give me example how to fill out in resume

edit: Thanks for the template. Here is what i applied
Microtrain Technology, Lombard. IL
Quality & Project Management in training, Jan 2016 to April 2017
Accomplished:

- ASQ-Certified Six Sigma Green Belt (SSGB) (2016)
- Certified Continuous Improvement Manager (CCIM)™ (2017)
- ITIL® V3 Foundation In IT Service Management Certified (2016)
- PMI-ACP® - PMI Agile Certified Practitioner (2016)

Comment: Yes, you should include it.   What reason might you have not to include it?  Do you have other qualifications/courses listed on your Resume?  (for example, school grades, college, university, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

The approach I would use is to put it in your "Education" section, like this:

```
[Professional Training School Name], [City], [State]

[Credential, if any] [Program of Study], [Month, Year start - Month, Year end]

* [Optional add bullet point with a short description of the program of study.]
```

Example:

> Arts & Crafts Academy, Santa Fe, NM
> Certificate, Basket Weaving Specialty, January 2017 - July 2017
>
> - Focus on traditional weaving techniques using grass straw and bison hair.

You can use the same approach for your certificates. If both certificates were from the same entity, combine then under that entity but list each on a separate line along with the date of receipt.